# WCF DataServices (CTP2): There is a type mismatch between the client and the service

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-data-services

I'm using WCF Dataservices CTP2 with Entity Framework 4.1. Now then I'm trying to get any data through my datacontext I get this exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation. --->
>   **System.InvalidOperationException:
>   There is a type mismatch between the
>   client and the service. Type
>   'Crm.Objects.Segmentation' is not
>   an entity type, but the type in the
>   response payload represents an entity
>   type. Please ensure that types defined
>   on the client match the data model of
>   the service, or update the service
>   reference on the client.**    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.MaterializeResolvedEntry(AtomEntry
>   entry, Boolean includeLinks)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.Materialize(AtomEntry
>   entry, Type expectedEntryType, Boolean
>   includeLinks)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.DirectMaterializePlan(AtomMaterializer
>   materializer, AtomEntry entry, Type
>   expectedEntryType)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializerInvoker.DirectMaterializePlan(Object
>   materializer, Object entry, Type
>   expectedEntryType)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.ProjectionPlan.Run(AtomMaterializer
>   materializer, AtomEntry entry, Type
>   expectedType)    at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.Read()
>   at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNextInternal()
>   at
>   System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.d_*b1`1.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at
>   MangoCrm.Modules.Replication.ReplicaBuilder.GetItems[T](IEnumerable`1
>   query)    at
>   MangoCrm.Modules.Replication.ReplicaBuilder.BeginReplication()
>   at
>   MangoCrm.Modules.Replication.ReplicationWindowControl.b*_0()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeType typeOwner)    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeType typeOwner)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object
>   obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks)    at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[]
>   args)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) 
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args,
>   Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

here is my code:

```
            var uri = new Uri(webServiceUrl);
            var service = new DataServiceContext(uri);
            MessageBox.Show(service.CreateQuery<Segmentation>("DbSegmentations").ToList().Count.ToString());
```

Any help?

**UPDATE**
ok now I found out that my WCF responce contains a modified entity object. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://localhost:99/Services/CrmDataService.svc/"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
       xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://localhost:99/Services/CrmDataService.svc/DbSegmentations(guid'e9854210-85d1-4822-ba70-7e1d3d29cf62')</id>
  <title type="text"></title>
  <updated>2011-06-16T15:07:48Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="Segmentation" href="DbSegmentations(guid'e9854210-85d1-4822-ba70-7e1d3d29cf62')" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Companies"
        type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"
        title="Companies"
        href="DbSegmentations(guid'e9854210-85d1-4822-ba70-7e1d3d29cf62')/Companies" />
  <category term="Crm.Data.Segmentation" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid">e9854210-85d1-4822-ba70-7e1d3d29cf62</d:Id>
      <d:Name>Promoter</d:Name>
      <d:Description m:null="true" />
      <d:ReplicaInfo m:type="Crm.Data.ReplicaInfo">
        <d:CreateDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2011-06-09T20:35:22.29</d:CreateDate>
        <d:ModifyDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2011-06-09T20:35:22.29</d:ModifyDate>
        <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Guid">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:CreatedById>
        <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Guid">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:ModifiedById>
        <d:IsDeleted m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsDeleted>
      </d:ReplicaInfo>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Here is a problem

```
 <category
 term="Crm.Data.Segmentation"
 scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"
 />
```

So the question is why my Crm.Objects.Segmentation became Crm.Data.Segmentation? Ho to change it back?

**UPDATE2**
I think the problem is in my data context. The data context has a namespace Crm.Data. My entities are in Crm.Objects. Then I use 4.0.0 WCF everything is fine, but then I switch to CTP2 my entities get Crm.Data namespace instead of a correct Crm.Objects

Answer (score 4):

Did you try implementing delegates for `DataServiceContext.ResolveName` and `DataServiceContext.ResolveType`?  Those 2 delegates, if provided, can be used to fixup the mapping between odata namespaces + names, and the types that are serialized and deserialized on the client.

Here is a simple example:

```
internal class CustomDataServiceContext : DataServiceContext
{
    public CustomDataServiceContext(Uri serviceRoot)
    : base(serviceRoot, DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3)
    {
        this.ResolveName = ResolveNameFromType;
        this.ResolveType = ResolveTypeFromName;
    }

    protected string ResolveNameFromType(Type clientType)
    {
        if (clientType.Namespace.Equals("ODataClient.MSProducts", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return string.Concat("ODataService.Models.", clientType.Name);
        }
        return clientType.FullName;
    }

    protected Type ResolveTypeFromName(string typeName)
    {
        if (typeName.StartsWith("ODataService.Models", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return this.GetType().Assembly.GetType(string.Concat("ODataClient.MSProducts", typeName.Substring(19)), false);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I had to do something like this (but I made it flexible instead of hard-coded) in order to make my entity classes work in the WCF Data Services client;

But even after doing this, I had this error:

System.InvalidOperationException : There is a type mismatch between the client and the service. Type WorkItem' is not an entity type, but the type in the response payload represents an entity type. Please ensure that types defined on the client match the data model of the service, or update the service reference on the client.

I found two fixes that worked for this:

1. Add a `[DataServiceKey("Id")]` attribute to your entity class.
   or
2. Rename your ~Id property so that it ends with `ID`

I figured out #2 the hard way - looking at the decompiled IL (this is for WCF Data Services 5.2.0).  After reviewing `ClientEdmModel` and `ClientTypeUtil`, I came across this method in `ClientTypeUtil`:

```
private static ClientTypeUtil.KeyKind IsKeyProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, DataServiceKeyAttribute dataServiceKeyAttribute)
{
  string name1 = propertyInfo.Name;
  ClientTypeUtil.KeyKind keyKind = ClientTypeUtil.KeyKind.NotKey;
  if (dataServiceKeyAttribute != null && dataServiceKeyAttribute.KeyNames.Contains(name1))
    keyKind = ClientTypeUtil.KeyKind.AttributedKey;
  else if (name1.EndsWith("ID", StringComparison.Ordinal))
  {
    string name2 = propertyInfo.DeclaringType.Name;
    if (name1.Length == name2.Length + 2 && name1.StartsWith(name2, StringComparison.Ordinal))
      keyKind = ClientTypeUtil.KeyKind.TypeNameId;
    else if (2 == name1.Length)
      keyKind = ClientTypeUtil.KeyKind.Id;
  }
  return keyKind;
}
```

It's that `name1.EndsWith("ID"` that is the key when using your POCOs on the client side of WCF Data Services.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you're referencing another implementation of the `Segmentation` class than the service's. Check out the namespace of `Segmentation` in your `CreateQuery<>()` call and the namespace of the `Segmentation` class in your service.

Comment: I have 3 projects in my solution: 1. client application 2. entity objects project 3. web site with WCF service project. So 1 and 3 has the same refferenece to 2 project. I'm sure I use the same refference in both projects.

Comment: Also I started to get this error after updating WCF services to CTP2

Comment: The code above is from your client application. It may resolve the Segmentation either as the one in the Entity Objects project, or the one generated by the WCF proxy.

Comment: I don't get it. I have the same reference to one object model everywhere in both projects...

Comment: Okay, I've just found out that the WCF xml responce contains this '<category term="Crm.Data.Segmentation" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />'. Why it becomes Data namespace?? It should be always Crm.Objects namespace!

Comment: It's probably because you didn't specify the namespace in your Data Contracts. But this should be fixed easily by configuring your Service Reference to reuse the types in your Entity Objects DLL. Just right-click the Service Reference, select Configure, select the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" checkbox, and pick the Entity Objects DLL in the list of assemblies below. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks Roy, but I don't use any service reference in my client application. As you may see in the code above I use generic call to my service using _DataServiceContext_.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think this is a bug of a new WCF CTP2. Then I added back the System.Data.Services 4.0.0 reference I got the correct Namespaces in my data service. But then I use v4.99.2.0 I get the wrong namespace in my ds.

Comment: One moment. I think thу reason is in my data context. The data context has a namespace Crm.Data. My entities are in Crm.Objects. Then I use 4.0.0 WCF everything is fine, but then I switch to CTP2 my entities get Crm.Data namespace instead of a correct Crm.Objects...

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, dont know whether or not it will fix yours.

What I had to do was to override the "CreateDataSource" method and turn off proxy creation in the svc.cs file.

Here's the code:

```
    protected override DataServiceContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        var db = base.CreateDataSource();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        return db;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same error message and fixed it on my end. Turns out I was mixing up assemblies between my service and client. One was using Microsoft.Data.Services, the other was using System.Data.Services.