# DataServiceContext & Linq: Select only inherited objects

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-data-services

I use WCF DataSerice and EF4.1 code-first (C#).

I have 2 entities:
1. Person
2. User inherited from Person class

I want to get only User objects from DbSet Persons. How can I do that?
Then I query dataervice like that:

```
service.CreateQuery<User>("DbPersons").OfType<User>().Execute();
```

I get an exception that OfType method is not supported by dataservice context.

> Error translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'OfType' is not supported.

Comment: What version of data services are you using. The standard version shipped with .NET 4.0 doesn't support `OfType` operator.

Comment: Hi, I have tried any version (including CTP2)

Comment: Did you try it on the June CTP? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-wcf-data-services-june-2011-ctp-for-net4-amp-sl4.aspx

Comment: just tryed it. Got another problem witch I described previously here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371243/wcf-dataservices-ctp2-there-is-a-type-mismatch-between-the-client-and-the-serv

Comment: Now I get this exception 'System.InvalidOperationException: There is a type mismatch between the client and the service. Type 'Crm.Objects.Departament' is not an entity type, but the type in the response payload represents an entity type. Please ensure that types defined on the client match the data model of the service, or update the service reference on the client.
   at System.Data.Services.Client.Ato'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved by adding service operation method.
See solution here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788.aspx

here is my code:

```
      public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("DbUsers", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
    }

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<User> DbUsers()
    {
        return CurrentDataSource.DbPersons.OfType<User>();
    }
```

and in your client application send request as usual:

```
service.CreateQuery<User>("DbUsers").Execute();
```