# Is it possible to intercept a response from a Data Service Query to materialize a different entity type?

Tags: wcf-data-services, iqueryable

I'm running out of ideas on a problem that I've got with WCF Data Services. The gist of it is that I'm executing a data service query which uses an interface to represent the queryable type.

```
DataServiceQuery<IOrder> queryable = base.CreateQuery<IOrder>("Orders");
```

Although the client successfully creates the query and the service processes it successfully, the response cannot be read by the client (presumably as it is not capable of creating an instance of the IOrder). I get the exception "There is a type mismatch between the client and the service". For some reason, the delegates on the context that handle resolving types from names are not called.

I was hoping that I'd be able to somehow marshal my implementation of IOrder onto a type that supported the interface. Is this something that is possible? Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

I am the owner of both the service and the client.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've moved on from this a long time ago but, for anyone else who is after the same thing, this can be achieved by setting the [ResolveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.resolvetype.aspx) property on the DataServiceContext.

Crimbo's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371243/wcf-dataservices-ctp2-there-is-a-type-mismatch-between-the-client-and-the-ser) question gives an example, albeit by sub-classing the DataServiceContext instead.

Comment: Nice! I have indeed moved away from data services though as they tended to be slow and cumbersome to deal with, mainly the amount of bandwidth used to transmit data in my case. I can't really test the above though so I think I can't mark your answer as accepted until I've actually tried it. Perhaps if someone else lands here they can? Hope thats ok!